# Calling OnPaintBackground

Tags: c#

I'm working on making the form's background to be transparent, so i tested the following code in some random project and it worked perfectly, but now when i applied it to a new project it hasn't been read during the load process as i tried to break point!! what am i doing wrong?

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(AFK_AIESEC.Properties.Resources.splash);
    this.locked.BackgroundImage = bmp;
}
```

Comment: It seems your new project is manually painting your background and thus skipping the system paint? What exactly are you hoping to achieve here?

Comment: well as you said im trying to manually paint the background so it can appear like a transparent splash screen with a .png transparent image on the background..

Comment: On that note, you would simply want to change your opacity, and set your background image on initialization or using the designer on the main form. Will post an answer shortly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ensure the OnPaint method is overridden, you should set your form style as follows in your constructor:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint 
              | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer
              | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw 
              | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer 
              | ControlStyles.UserPaint
              , true);
```

The important setting there is ControlStyles.UserPaint which tells it that you want to handle the painting yourself.

Comment: with this code it would make the form semi-transparent and the background to be splash.png.. but what i wanted is the whole form with no backcolor, background or anything with just the components inside.

Comment: actually the OnPaintBackground() worked perfectly but it hasn't been read during the load process. that was the main problem!

Comment: For that, you'd have to set your FormBorderStyle to None, then `Opacity` to 0, you should also update your question accordingly .

Comment: Sorry, I seem to be missing something here. What exactly is the problem? How do you mean it worked perfectly?

Comment: at first the code worked when i tried it in a previous project and it was loaded.. but now when i tried the same code in a different project it didn't load! the code works but it just didn't load!

Comment: I don't exactly know how you're trying to achieve your Splashscreen and I was focusing but take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446493.aspx) to see the proper way to do a splash screen. However I've provided a more generic answer to the question. Good day