# Painting Issue after resizing winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, repaint

I am having an issue when resizing my winform. I wanted to give an specific background color to all my forms so I have overriden the OnPaintBackground method as it follows

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        ResizeRedraw = true;

        using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(ClientRectangle, Color.LightBlue, Color.CornflowerBlue, 90F))
        {
           e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
```

On the form I have also a GroupBox which contains textboxes, labels, etc and its backcolor is being set as Transparent. When the winform is executed for the very first time works fine, but when I minimize the winform and then maximize a RED CROSS appears inside the groupbox.

I have reviewed lots of cases but most of them talk about flickering but this is not the case. I have also read about how the painting works, apparently when the winform is displayed first tells the child controls to paint themselves, but as the father hasn't being painted yet then the control does not know what to paint as transparent aspect for the background of the control.

Here's an example of how it looks like after resizing.

[image: Resize showing RED CROSS]

Thanks in advanced for your help!

PS:I am using Visual Studio 2012, C#.

Comment: Red cross appears if your procedure throws unhandled exception. Wrap it in try:catch block and break at the exception. Maybe the exception description can give you a hint

Comment: Miroslav Thanks for your answer, indeed I have tried your advice and put the exception into a messageBox when going through the catch line; Here's what it says: Rectangle Width or Height cannot be equal to "0". I have put the next conditional and it worked perfectly fine!! Thanks a lot for the tip on how to debbug my app. Here's the final code

Comment: I put the code inside a try catch statement and added this next condition if (ClientRectangle.Width != 0 && ClientRectangle.Height != 0)
                {//Redraw here}

Answer (score -1):

I have found an article here: [Calling OnPaintBackground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475275/calling-onpaintbackground)

In which the answer to the question was with how the OnPaintBackground was being overridden, to ensure that it works properly he said that you should set your form style to the following

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint 
              | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer
              | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw 
              | ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer 
              | ControlStyles.UserPaint
              , true);
```

The `.UserPaint` just tells it that you're handling the painting yourself to ensure that it is not being handled by anything else so that it is overridden correctly.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I have already tried that possible solution. If you pay attention I have already set ResizeRedraw and DoubleBuffered properties as true in my code. Those properties solved the issue on the form background, but not inside the groupbox where I am still having the issue. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: After it paints it, and the labels are like that; try moving the form around your desktop. Is it still like that? I'm just curious if it's a "refresh" issue so by moving your form it should refresh it.

Comment: Frank, check my answer to Miroslav comment. I have already solved the issue. Thanks for your support too!

Comment: Ahh, I'm sorry I didn't see that. Thank you for pointing it out, glad it got solved!